# UWP Xbox One page navigation when using WebView

Tags: c#, webview, uwp, xbox-one

Usually when running a UWP app on Xbox the B button on the controller is handled automatically and will return you to the previous page.

I have a page which contains a WebView, when you use the directional buttons to place the focus box around that control, the B button no longer responds.  You can use the A button to take control of the WebView and display the pointer and the B button then will return focus back as above but I cannot navigate back using the B button until you move the focus box to a different control.  This also happens using AdControl since this uses WebView.

I have tried to capture KeyDown:

```
Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyDown += CoreWindow_KeyDown;

private void CoreWindow_KeyDown(Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow sender, Windows.UI.Core.KeyEventArgs args)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(args.VirtualKey.ToString());
}
```

This responds with GamePadB, GamePadX etc but not when the focus box is around the WebView.

Is there anyway I can find out when the GamePad buttons (specifically B) are pressed when the focus box is around the WebView (or AdControl) and the control isn't engaged so I can manually invoke the backstack navigation?

Comment: When we use the mouse mode for the XBOX app, the B button will work very well and navigate back. 
I can reproduce this issue when using the XY focus mode, I will do further testing about this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this issue happens when using the XY focus mode for the app, if your OS version is 14393 or higher, one workaround for this issue is to use the mouse mode for this page which contains the webview by setting RequiresPointer="WhenFocused" as following:

```
<Page RequiresPointer="WhenFocused">
...
</Page>
```

And set another page to XY focus mode by using the following code in the app.xaml.cs:

```
this.RequiresPointerMode =
   Windows.UI.Xaml.ApplicationRequiresPointerMode.WhenRequested;
```

For more information, please try to refer to the following article:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/input-and-devices/designing-for-tv#mouse-mode

Comment: Unfortunately that means I'll have to use mouse mode on each page that contains an AdControl or Webview (which is every page!).  Hopefully something can be done to rectify this in the Creators update when this reaches the Xbox One