# UWP Xbox One Mouse Mode and right thumbstick scrolling in ScrollViewer

Tags: uwp, xbox-one

A few month ago I published a UWP app to the Xbox One but on certain pages I had to have Mouse Mode enabled due to the fact that if you had any WebViews on that page (including AdControls) the system would not pickup the GamePad B button to activate the backstack (full details here: [UWP Xbox One page navigation when using WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41481240/uwp-xbox-one-page-navigation-when-using-webview) )

Anyway.. things worked fine, move the pointer over a ScrollViewer and you could then use the right thumbstick to scroll up/down.  I've now revisited the app to make some changes and noticed that this feature no longer works, using the right thumbstick no longer controls the ScrollViewer and you have to manually place the pointer onto the scroll bar, hold GamePad A and move it using the left thumbstick.

Is this a undocumented feature (bug!) introduced since my Xbox was updated to the Creators Build?  And is there a way to bring this feature back to my ScrollViewer?

Many Thanks,

Stu

Comment: "I've now revisited the app to make some changes and noticed that this feature no longer works" . For this, could you please details what changes you have made? Are you sure the mouse mode is still enabled? Can the left thumbstick work well for navigation after you made the "changes"?